# How to fetch only all webmethod in class at runtime using reflaction class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i inherit webservice in particular class and at runtime i want to fetch all only webmethod which are declare in webservice class which inherit in particulr class ... i want to fetch only webmethod from that class which inherit webservice class..

Comment: What do you mean with webservice class? Do you mean a webservice proxy class on client side that inherits from class SoapHttpClientProtocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection to get all of the methods of a class and then see which ones have an [OperationContract] attribute.  You can use linq to do this in a single statement as follows:

```
var methods = typeof(Service1).GetMethods()
                              .Where(meth => meth.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                                                 .Where(attr => attr is OperationContractAttribute)
                                                 .Count() > 0);
```

By specifying "true" for the bool flag in GetCustomAttributes, the code will pull attributes from the method's entire inheritance chain.